# IOS 5.0 - NSURLConnection works but returns Null before completing

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have a class file called functions where I keep repetitive tasks.  One of the functions in there is called GetPrice which connects to an XML web service, parses the XML and returns a CarPrice object.  Everything works great until it's time to return the CarPrice object.  It is NULL even though in my connectionDidFinishLoading, the object is not null.

Here is my GetPrice function:

```
-(CarPrice*)GetPrice:(NSString *)m
{
    NSString *url =[@"http://myUrl.com"];

    dataWebService = [NSMutableData data];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [conn start];
    return mp;  //mp is declared as a CarPrice in the @interface section of my funcs class

    //when it gets returned here it is NULL even though....(see below)
}


//Connection Functions=======================


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

    [dataWebService setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [dataWebService appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    ParserMetal *pmr = [ParserMetal alloc];
    mp = [pmr parseMetal:responseString];
    //at this point, the mp is fully populated
    //an NSLOG(@"%@", mp.displayPrice); here will show that the mp object is populated
    //however as stated above, when it returns, it is null.
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Error during Connection: %@", [error description]);
}

//End Connection Functions ==================
```

Is the `return mp;` happening before the mp gets populated?  Do I need to use a Synchronous connection here to make sure the data is populated before the return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you are going to call `GetPrice:m:` and then start the connection from there. After you start the connection by using `[connection start]`, you immediately return `mp`.

This means that the connection is started, but before it has received all its data, you already return `mp`. You should wait for the data to be received, and then return `mp`.

You could use a Synchronous method for this, or you could implement a method in your main class, which is going to be called from within the `connectionDidFinishLoading:connection:` method, defined in your 'other class file'. Like this:

- Start connection
- Receive data...
- Call `[mainClass didReceiveAllData:mp]`

Hope this helps.

Comment: by mainClass, do you mean the MainViewController where the GetPrice function is being called?

Im not really sure how to do that....

The problem I have is that I make several calls to the function like so:

    CarPrice *hp = [fn GetPrice:@"honda"];
    CarPrice *tp = [fn GetPrice:@"toyota"];
    CarPrice *cp = [fn GetPrice:@"chevrolet"];

I need the those objects assigned before I can really continue with the application...I'm not sure how I'd assign those objects inside of a `didReceiveAllData:mp]` function and be able to keep them as distinct objects.

Comment: Also, is there an actual working demo of something like this that anyone knows about?  A tutorial or something.  I'm a C# developer, so pseudocode doesn't really work for me in this context as I have no example to compare it to

Comment: Regarding your first comment: yes. You should define a function (for example 'didReceiveAllData', but you can call it whatever you want it to be called) and then handle all the incoming information there. That method should be in the class where you're going to call [fn GetPrice], for example your MainViewController as you said. I don't think there's a good code example on this. However, if you're not that good at Objective C and delegates and stuff, you might just want to stick to a Synchronous connection, which is a lot easier to use in your case.

Comment: I was able to change my function to a void function and then instead of returning a Null object, in the connectionDidFinishLoading I call a function in my main view controller and pass the data populated object back through that.  The problem I am having now is that the function that accepts the object doesn't seem to be able to update a label.text on my main view.....

Comment: I think that's because you are using multiple threads now. You have thread on which the data is being loaded from the web, and you have a thread running the UI. You can only change your UI from the thread that handles your UI - you are now trying to do that from within the NSURLConnection generated thread. Try looking up NSNotificationCenter, might you out. Otherwise, you might want to start a new question.

Comment: Thanks!  I did start a new question and yes I believe you are correct.  When the data returns, the NSLabel is a null object and has no value even though it doesn't generate a compile-time error since the label is an @property of the view controller.  Anyway, thanks again...1 step at a time